# Custom CMS written in PHP, should I be sending HTTP content-length header to clients?

Tags: php, content-management-system, seo, http-headers, content-length

I've built a custom content management system on our intranet which allows us to update news articles and content across several sites that I operate. It appears to be working well.

However the other day I suddenly remembered that I'm not sending the HTTP content-length header when outputting articles on the websites. I send last-modified using the modification date of the article from the database.

Just wondering if I should also calculate the content-length of the whole page before it's sent to the client? Would it be best practice to send the content-length header or does it have any significant search engine benefits?

Cheers, B

Comment: Doesn't Your webserver do it already? My do.

Comment: Sometimes. But other times I see transfer-encoding: chunked. I was wondering if there's any standards/SEO benefit to content-length vs chunked.

Answer (score 0):

You are required by the [standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) section 14.13 to send content-length... only exception is when you use "chunked transfer", but for that you have some other requirements...

Comment: In my PHP application I send the whole content to the browser in one echo statement. There's "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" in the response headers but I'm not sending that manually. So it must be generated automatically by PHP/Apache. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes - that happens when either you don't provide a content-length and/or the client requests "chunked" transfer...

Comment: And therefore I don't need to send my own content-length? After some investigation I notice that some PHP scripts send an automatically calculated content-length and others send transfer-encoding: chunked. Do you have any info as to what conditions cause PHP to send different headers?

Comment: no - there are several factors (HTTP 1.0 doesn't support chunked), some proxies don't too, some clients don't etc. - if performance is not absolutely critical and I can calculate the content-length then I would go server-side always with content-length

Comment: I'm not worried about the marginal decrease in performance that such a calculation would cause. How would I calculate the content-length in PHP, using strlen() on the output? We use UTF-8 throughout so I assume I DON'T want mb_strlen() because I want to know the number of bytes - not the number of characters.

Comment: I don't know much about PHP - your question so far have been mostly about HTTP protocol... but on PHP I will have to give up...